# How to keep code from replaying same message?

Tags: java

After typing in a wrong response other than the 2 .txt files the code should say  File 'double_input3.txt' does not exist. Please enter the file name again:. But its also adding Please enter the file name again.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class boost
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      double sum = 0.0;   
      double count = 0.0;
      double avg = 0.0;

      while (true)
          {
          @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

          System.out.print("Please enter the file name: \n");
          String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

          if(filename.equals(null)){
              break;
          }



          File file = new File(filename);
          if (!file.exists()){
              System.out.println("File 'double_input3.txt' does not exist ");
              System.out.println("Please enter the file name again:");
              continue;
          }

          Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

          DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
          df.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);



          while (inputFile.hasNext())
          {

             double number = inputFile.nextDouble();


             sum = sum + number;
             count++;
             avg = ((double) sum / count);

          }




          System.out.println("Total: " + df.format(sum));
          System.out.println("Average: "+ df.format(avg));
          inputFile.close();
          if (file.exists()){
              break;
          }
      }



   }
}
```

Comment: Have you typed the filename correctly? and are you sure the executable file and the files are in same directory?

Comment: Yes the executables and everything works its just when you type in the wrong name of the .txt i need it to say File 'double_input3.txt' does not exist. Please enter the file name again: but its also including the please enter file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move this line

```
System.out.print("Please enter the file name: \n");
```

before the `while` loop, so that it is only printed once

**edit**

This code works

```
    System.out.print("Please enter the file name: \n");

    while (true)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

        if(filename.equals(null)){
            break;
        }



        File file = new File(filename);
        if (!file.exists()){
            System.out.println("File 'double_input3.txt' does not exist ");
            System.out.println("Please enter the file name again:");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    System.out.println("finsihed");
```

**output**

```
Please enter the file name: 
nothere
File 'double_input3.txt' does not exist 
Please enter the file name again:
c:/temp/a.txt
finsihed
```

Comment: This worked but now its making me press enter twice to print the answer

Comment: by moving a print statement is not going to cause any extra `key` presses that were not there before.  Have a look at my edited code

Comment: Sorry I just saw this and i just accepted your answer and i gave you an upvote but im at less than 15 reputation right now since I am new to this site I just made an account.

Comment: Thanks Mate, much appreciated